# generating a LayoutParams based on the type of parent

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

I find myself needing to create a View completely in Java without knowing what concrete type the parent is.

example:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(null == convertView){
        convertView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
    }
    ((TextView) convertView).setText(getItem(position).getName());
}
```

Now suppose I wanted to change this so that the convertView was wrap_content in both directions.  Since this is an Adapter, I'd like to avoid coupling the Adapter with the concrete type of the parent, but the LayoutParams I give it in setLayoutParams() has to be the correct concrete type otherwise the app will crash (i.e. if parent is a ListView it has to be ListView.LayoutParams, if it's a LinearLayout it must be a LinearLayout.LayoutParams, etc.).  I don't want to use a switch statement either since that's just a more flexible form of coupling, and if I attach this adapter to a view I didn't anticipate I still end up with a crash.  Is there a generic way to do this?

Comment: +1 For wanting to code "the right way"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using the following code:

```
LayoutParams params = parent.generateLayoutParams(null);
```

**EDIT**:
The method above doesn't work because `ViewGroup.generateLayoutParams()` requires `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to be set in the passed `AttributeSet`.

<s>If you use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` with any layout then everything will work fine. But if you use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` with `RelativeLayout` for example, then an exception will be thrown.</s>

**EDIT**:
There's one working solution for this problem which I don't really like. The solution is to call `generateLayoutParams()` with valid `AttributeSet`. You can create an `AttributeSet` object using at least two different approaches. One of them I've implemented:

**res\layout\params.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dip" />
```

**SomeActivity.java**:

```
private void addView(ViewGroup viewGroup, View view) {
    viewGroup.addView(view);
    view.setLayoutParams(generateLayoutParams(viewGroup));
}

private ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getLayout(R.layout.params);
    try {
        while(parser.nextToken() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            // Skip everything until the view tag.
        }
        return viewGroup.generateLayoutParams(parser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Another way to create an `AttributeSet` object is to implement `AttributeSet` interface and make it return `android:layout_width`, `android:layout_height` and other layout attributes you need.

Comment: This causes a runtime exception: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

Comment: That seems to be true according to the source code. To use this method you have to provide an object that implements `AttributeSet` and can be used to get `layout_width` and `layout_height` values. And I don't know any simple way to create such an object. Are you sure you need to provide concrete `LayoutParams` subclasses? I always use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and everything works fine.

Comment: I've had it crash on me before and troubleshot it down to that.

Comment: I think if you use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` with any layout then everything will work fine. But if you use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` with `RelativeLayout` for example, then an exception will be thrown.

Comment: I know I'm late... but this answer is wrong. Using Viewgroup.LayoutParams instead of, for instance, TableRow.LayoutParams  is not good. I ran into many cases where views simply do not display as a result. Furthermore, ViewGroup.LayoutParams lacks methods you may want to use, such as setMargin.

Comment: Doesn't work. Set a ViewGroup.LayoutParams on your view and then add it to a RelativeLayout. Result: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: @aleph-null, I've added a working solution to the answer. It's not very elegant, but I hope it will help you.

Comment: @cdhabecker, take a look at the new solution. Maybe it will be useful for you.

Comment: @Michael Do you know how long ive tried creating my own AttributeSet object!!! You just made my day, thanks!

Comment: @Michael well, I dont see the AttributeSet example, but your suggestion on how to use it will suffice.

Comment: @SamusArin, maybe I'll add it if I have enough time to do it. But I can't promise. If you have a working sample, you can add it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following workaround for this:

```
View view = new View(context);
parent.addView(view);

LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
//Do whatever you need with the parameters
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You cannot autogenerate the correct `LayoutParams` yourself unless you do something hacky, so you should just create a situation where they will be autogenerated for you: just add the view to the container. After that you can get them from the view and do what you need.

The only caveat is that if you don't need to add the view to the container yourself, you'll have to remove the view from it later, but this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for `ListAdapters` since the `View` will be added to the parent after `getView()` returns

Comment: @keyboardr It's not a problem, you can add a view yourself, get the parameters, and remove it.

Answer (score 2):

All `LayoutParams` classes have one general superclass: `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. And all popular layouts (`FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, etc.) use `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` as base class for their respective `LayoutParams` classes.

So if you just need width, height and margins, you can create `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` and pass it as layout params to any subclass of `ViewGroup`.  What will happen then is container will automatically convert more generic `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` into its own layout parameters using `protected LayoutParams ViewGroup#generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p)`.

This code will work for any `container` class, including `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc:

```
val layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
container.addView(view, layoutParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

***why no one (yet -> see 2016.05) has mentioned here an approach based on reflections ?***

**1. entry point:**

```
 /**
 *  generates default layout params for given view group 
 *  with width and height set to WLayoutParams.RAP_CONTENT 
 *
 * @param viewParent - parent of this layout params view 
 * @param <L> - layout param class 
 * @return layout param class object 
 * @throws NoSuchMethodException
 * @throws InvocationTargetException
 * @throws IllegalAccessException
 */
@NonNull
private <L extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams> L generateDefaultLayoutParams(@NonNull ViewGroup viewParent)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Method generateDefaultLayoutParamsMethod = ViewGroup.class.getDeclaredMethod("generateDefaultLayoutParams");
      // caution: below way to obtain method has some flaw  as we need traverse superclasses to obtain method in case we look in object and not a class             
      // = viewParent.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("generateDefaultLayoutParams");
    generateDefaultLayoutParamsMethod.setAccessible(true);
    return (L) generateDefaultLayoutParamsMethod.invoke(viewParent);
}
```

**2. usages:**

```
@NonNull
protected <T extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams> T createLayoutParamsForView(ViewGroup viewParent,
                                                                         @IdRes int belowViewId)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    return createLayoutParamsForView(null,null,viewParent,belowViewId);
}

@NonNull
protected <T extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams> T createLayoutParamsForView(@NonNull Context context,
                                                                         @NonNull Class<? extends ViewGroup> parentClass,
                                                                         @IdRes int belowViewId)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    return createLayoutParamsForView(context,parentClass,null,belowViewId);
}

@NonNull
private <T extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams> T createLayoutParamsForView(@Nullable Context context,
                                                                       @Nullable Class<? extends ViewGroup> parentClass,
                                                                       @Nullable ViewGroup parent,
                                                                       @IdRes int belowViewId)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    if(context == null && parent == null) throw new IllegalStateException("either context and parent class or must be non null!");
    T layoutParams = (T) (parent != null ? generateDefaultLayoutParams(parent) : generateDefaultLayoutParams(context, parentClass));
    if (belowViewId != NO_ID  && RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.class.isAssignableFrom(layoutParams.getClass())){
        ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)layoutParams).addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, belowViewId);
    }
    return layoutParams;
}

@NonNull
private <P extends ViewGroup> P instantiateParent(Class parentClass, Context context) 
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Constructor constructor = parentClass.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class);
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    return (P) constructor.newInstance(context);
}

@NonNull
private <L extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams, P extends ViewGroup> L generateDefaultLayoutParams(Context context, @NonNull Class<? extends ViewGroup> viewParentClass) 
        throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    P viewParent = instantiateParent(viewParentClass, context);
    return generateDefaultLayoutParams(viewParent);
}
```

Comment: Because reflection on Android is costly.

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek "was"  we have now a modern devices (4/8 cores & 2-6gb ram)  so for user experience the cost is nothing - if you consider different please post a proof